# Shorter way of if statements in python

Tags: python, if-statement

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
if "a" in l and "b" in l and "c" in l and "d" in l:
   pass
```

What's a shorter way of writing this if statement?

Tried:

```
if ("a" and "b" and "c" and "d") in l:
    pass
```

But this seems to be incorrect. What's the correct way?
Python 3

Comment: Heard about `all` and `any`?

Comment: Note that the second snippet evaluates to `if "a" in l:`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An idea might be to use [`all(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and a generator:

```
if all(x in l for x in ['a','b','c','d']):
    pass
```

All takes as input any kind of iterable and checks that for all elements the iterable emits, `bool(..)` is `True`.

Now within `all` we use a generator. A generator works like:

```
<expr> for <var> in <other-iterable>
```

(with no braces)

It thus takes every element in the `<other-iterable>` and calls the `<expr>` on it. In this case the `<expr>` is `x in l`, and `x` is the `<var>`:

```
#         <var>
#           |
 x in l for x in ['a','b','c','d']
#\----/          \---------------/
#<expr>           <other-iterable>
```

Further explanation of [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Answer (score 6):

You can use sets:

```
l = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' }

if { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' } <= l:
    pass
```

Answer (score 5):

```
l = "abcde"
if all(c in l for c in "abcd"):
    pass
```

Comment: I think the OP is giving an example here with one-char strings, evidently in real life one probably checks against multi-char strings, but good answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 4):

A different approach is using sets:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
if set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).issubset(set(l)):
  pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `set` objects for such case:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
if  set(l) >= set(("a", "b", "c", "d")):
    print('pass')
```

> **set >= other**
>
> Test whether every element in other is in the set.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set.issuperset